# Pandas gives me a SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create two new columns in my dataframe depending on the values of the columns Subscribers, External Party and Direction. If the Direction is I for Incoming, column a should become External Party and col B should become Subscriber. If the Direction is O for Outgoing, it should be the other way around. I use the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
...
df['a'] = np.where((df.Direction == 'I'), df['External Party'], df['Subscriber'])
df['b'] = np.where((df.Direction == 'O'), df['External Party'], df['Subscriber'])
```

I get a SettingWithCopyWarning from Pandas, but the code does what it needs to do. How can I improve this operation to avoid the error?
Thanks in advance!
Jo

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the place in your code where *df* is **created**.

Most probably, it is a **view** of another DataFrame, something like:

```
df = df_src[...]
```

Then any atempt to save something in *df* causes just this warning.

To avoid it, create *df* as a truly **independent** DataFrame, with its
own data buffer. Something like:

```
df = df_src[...].copy()
```

Now *df* has its own data buffer, and can be modified without the
above warning.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to work with the same df later on in your code then it is sometimes useful to create a deep copy of the df before making any iterations.

Pandas native `copy` method is not always acting as one would expect - here is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59826571/pandas-dataframe-copydeep-true-doesnt-actually-create-deep-copy) that might give more insights.

You can use `copy` module that comes with python to copy the entire object and to ensure that there are no links between 2 dataframes.

```
import copy
df_copy = copy.deepcopy(df)
```